# Shell script : Reading yml with dynamic property key

Tags: shell, unix, yaml, sh

My YML file is:

```
marketVal:
  envVal:
    hostVal: ipValue
```

and running shell script by  `sh myscript.sh marketVal envVal`

And in .sh file I am reading it as

```
market $1
env $2
parse_yaml() {
  local prefix=$2
  local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
  sed -ne "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
    -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
  awk -F$fs '{
indent = length($1)/2;
vname[indent] = $2;
for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
  if (length($3) > 0) {
   vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
   printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
  }
 }'
}

eval $(parse_yaml hostList.yml "config_")

#Here my property key is "config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal"
# so the value of "config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal" is properly coming as "ipValue"
echo ${config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal}
#As I can not hard code the marketVal etc so the key will be like
# "config_${market}_${env}__hostVal"
```

Now if I am doing some thing like this in script

```
key="config_${market}_${env}_hostVal"
echo ${key}
ip_value=${key}
echo ${ip_value}
```

It is printing.
    `config_${market}_${env}_hostVal
    *nothing get printed for echo ${ip_value}*`
Whereas the expected output is:

```
config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal
ipValue
```

Can any one suggest what to do here to read this value, I am very new to the shell scripting, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is working, I tried

```
$ market="x"
$ env="y"
$ key="config_${market}_${env}_hostVal"
$ echo $key
config_x_y_hostVal
$ ip_value=${key}
$ echo ${ip_value}
config_x_y_hostVal
```

What you are getting when executing echo ${key}?